# How to set ParaVIew 5 to use Ofscreen rendering from python?

Tags: python, paraview

So ParaView 5 builds [come with prebuild ofscreen rendering](https://blog.kitware.com/messing-with-mesa-for-paraview-5-0vtk-7-0/). When one uses ParaView UI one can set stuff like `./paraview --mesa-swr-avx2` for it to run mesa renderer. I use Jupyter, and ParaView in conjunction with tons of other libraries. How to set ParaView rendering settings from python code (in version 5+)?

Answer (score 0):

The prebuilt mesa is managed in ParaView binaries by providing a forwarding executable that sets up appropriate environment variables before exec-ing the real **paraview** executable to ensure Mesa OpenGL libraries are loaded. Hence, there's no way to set those up through Python script. You determine the environment variables that are needed to be set by executing paraview as follows:

```
paraview --mesa-swr-avx2 --print
```

You should be able to set those up separately in your environment and hopefully that'd work.